# Problem running systemctl in centos7 based container

Tags: systemd, docker

Error message from docker log command : `Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted`

My docker file:

```
`From centos:latest
MAINTAINER Ijaz <ihmad@example.com>
RUN yum -y update; yum clean all
RUN yum -y install httpd
RUN echo "This is our new apache server on centos6" > /var/www /html/index.html

EXPOSE 80

RUN echo "/bin/systemctl start httpd.service" >> /root/.bashrc`
```

Have anyone experienced this , or fixed it?

Answer (score 2):

The `systemctl` command communicates with `systemd`.  `systemd` is not running in your container, hence the error.

While it is *possible* to run `systemd` in a container, it is not a typical use case.  For what you are doing, it would be far more common to start `httpd` directly, e.g.:

```
CMD ["/usr/sbin/httpd", "-DFOREGROUND"]
```